# Differentiate between page refresh and normal page load from navigating

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC C#, I used `Context.Request.Headers["Referer"]` to get the referrer information from which page it is navigated to. But when I refresh the page, it still shows the old referrer url.

Is there any way that I can differentiate the page refresh and page load by navigation?

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            var referrer = '@Context.Request.Headers["Referer"]';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [window.onbeforeload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to set a cookie/sessionStorage value, the event is triggered before page refreshes or a new page is to be loaded.

```
// Vanilla JavaScript
window.addEventListener('onbeforeload', function() {
  // your code to set value here
});

// jQuery
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  // your code to set value here
});
```

After the page is loaded ([window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)), you can check for the value. If it matches you know the page is refreshed. You must also delete it at this point.

```
// Vanilla JavaScript
window.onload = function() {
  // your code to check value here
  // remember to delete the value too
});

// jQuery
$(window).on('load', function() {
  // your code to check value here
  // remember to delete the value too
});
```

The `load` event fires at the end of the document loading process - all of the objects in the document are in the DOM at this point. If you want to perform the check as soon as possible you can use an IIFE:

```
(function refreshCheck() {
  // your check here
  // remember to delete the value too
})();
```